# How can I make IntelliJ IDEA update my dependencies from Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I manually add dependencies in the ***pom.xml*** of my project, let *Maven* download the dependencies and let *IntelliJ* build the module, *IntelliJ* complains about missing libraries. At the same time *Maven* can find the dependent JARs and build the project.

How can I tell *IntelliJ* to use the libs which are downloaded by *Maven*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)

Comment: Modern versions of Intellij prompts in a baloon to import changes or enable auto import.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Maven auto import automatically in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099526/how-to-disable-maven-auto-import-automatically-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't have to reimport manually each time.  You can enable auto-import [as documented here.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html)  Change this in Settings -> Maven -> Import Maven projects automatically.

Comment: In later versions of IntelliJ, the option can be found under File -> Setttings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing.

Comment: This has now gone away (2020.1), and you have to click the maven button that appears over the pom file while you're editing it :(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099526/how-to-disable-maven-auto-import-automatically-in-intellij-idea#comment109512099_26099587

Comment: @AntonyStubbs interestingly for me nothing seems to appear...well a small icon that seems to indicate an auto-update, but any added dependency is only available after manual reload. Seems to me like the fully automated new way is still a bit buggy... or I'm missing something... ah, you already linked to the changes in the other answer, so for anyone following up, checkout: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/?_ga=2.166486142.1328458743.1589984167-1329951468.1589984167#maven_and_gradle_importing_updates

Comment: @FrankHopkins yeah in 2020.1 you have to click that button manually when it appears. The only automated maven update is when the files change outside of idea (like you check out a different branch). It's been put back in 2020.2 but you have to _turn on the setting_ - see the issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235459#focus=Comments-27-4302337.0-0

Comment: @AntonyStubbs ah great! thanks for the info! It's funny, I never had issues with clicking on the notification window, but the little button that was supposed to be less obstructive is so unobstructive I didn't even notice it until I started looking as to why it didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 75):

It turns out IntelliJ does not pick up added dependencies from the local Maven repository. We have to tell IntelliJ to reimport the pom.xml.

1. Open the project view in IntelliJ
2. Right click the pom.xml file and select Maven > Reimport *or* Maven > Reload (for newer versions of IntelliJ)
3. If this works for you IntelliJ will add the dependencies to the project
4. Check the if the dependencies you need are added in

- File - Project Structure - Project Settings - Libraries
- and File - Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies

Answer (score 28):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2016

#### Import Maven projects automatically

**Approach 1**

- **File** > **Settings...** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Build Tools** > **Maven** > **Importing** > check **Import Maven projects automatically**

  [image: Import Maven projects automatically]

**Approach 2**

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > type "Import Maven" > choose "Import Maven projects automatically" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> > check **Import Maven projects automatically**

#### Reimport

**Approach 1**

- In Project view, right click on your project folder > **Maven** > **Reimport**

**Approach 2**

- **View** > **Tools Windows** > **Maven Projects**:

  - right click on your project > Reimport

  or

  - click on the "Reimport All Maven Projects" icon:

    [image: Reimport All Maven Projects]

Comment: I don't see Maven option after right clicking project folder. Do I need to install Maven plugin separately with IDEA ?

Comment: @vikramvi yes you need to install maven first. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS323/Installing+Apache+Maven+on+Windows I might be too late but I'm adding this comment for the ones who will face it in the future.

Comment: I'm using _ideaIU-2021.2_ and this `reimport` shows as `reload`.

Answer (score 20):

You need to go to: Maven settings -> Auto-Reload Settings

[image: Auto-Reload Settings]

Then check "Any Changes":

[image]

Comment: For macOS users, beside above entry point from Maven on the right side of the IDE, you can: IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> check "Reload project after changes in the build scripts" and select "Any changes". Works for my IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1.

Answer (score 10):

Uncheck

> **"Work Offline"**

in Settings -> Maven !
 It worked for me ! :D

Answer (score 10):

File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Maven>
Check : Always update snapshot

That worked for me.

Comment: For me too. *IntelliJ* is too intelligent to succeed where `Eclipse` and `mvn clean install` on a command line are able too. Hours lost. I hate pedantic software.

Answer (score 7):

Todays, there is a `Reload Project` option under the `Maven` tab when you do mouse right-click inside the **pom.xml** file.

[image: Reload Maven dependencies]

Answer (score 5):

I tried absolutely everything to get IntelliJ to pickup my `pom.xml` changes but it just wasn't doing it. I commented out all of the `<dependencies>` in `pom.xml` and rebuilt the project which should've shown hundreds of compile errors but didn't.

In the end, I had to delete the `.idea` folder to get IntelliJ to regenerate it's maven model. Once I did this, subsequent changes to `pom.xml` were picked up when I did a "Reload All Projects" so I suspect a bug where IntelliJ is using a cached model rather than updating it when changes are made.

Here's what I did:

1. Close the project in IntelliJ (file -> close project)
2. Delete the `.idea` folder in the root folder of the project
3. Open the project again in IntelliJ
4. Maven -> Reload All Projects
5. Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 3):

For some reason IntelliJ (at least in version 2019.1.2) ignores dependencies in local `.m2` directory. None of above solutions worked for me. The only thing finally forced IntelliJ to discover local dependencies was:

1. Close project
2. Open project clicking on `pom.xml` (not on a project directory)
3. Click `Open as Project`

[image: List item]

4. Click `Delete Existing Project and Import`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in **IntelliJ 2020** in the `pom.xml` view one should be able to apply pom changes by following key combination: <kbd>CTRG</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

And as correctly commented before - IntelliJ additionally shows a balloon widget to import changes.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from checking 'Import Maven projects automatically', make sure that settings.xml file from File > Settings > Maven > User Settings file exist, If doesn't exist then override and provide your settings.xml file path.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the project , removed it from recent projects, deleted the .idea dir and then re-imported the project. After that, Intellij starting re-importing the dependency.