# IntelliJ not updating updated Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have been using [version 1.3.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2) of [`commons-io`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) before for project A. On project B I used the newest [version 2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4). Now I want to add Project B's `JAR` as library to project A. Since project B uses functionalities that didn't exist yet in commons-io version 1.3.2 I updated the `pom.xml` of project A to use version 2.4 for commons-io:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when I try to run the code in project A which calls libraries in project B, I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
```

since [`IntelliJ`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) didn't seem to realize that the libraries have updated.

I tried [re-importing the Maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765077/3764804) and deleting the local directory containing the commons-io libraries `C:\Users\Name\.m2\repository\commons-io` but that didn't work either. How do I fix this and make IntelliJ become aware of the updated classes such as `FileUtils`? Their decompiler for example shows me the old byte code version still when I peek definitions but it is supposed to update it according to the `pom.xml`.

I have [import Maven projects automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993387/3764804) checked by the way.

Comment: Can you check your maven configuration within IntelliJ to check whether you have the correct local repo? After that, delete the commons-io directory again and confirm that it's gone, then go back to idea and click the reimport button on the maven window again. Then, check if the commons-io directory has been recreated and see what it contains. If it has more than you expect, try `mvn dependency:tree` on the command line, and check for the commons-io dependencies to see if you understand where each version is coming from. Then, report your results back here.

Comment: @EngineerDollery:
I resolved the issue. The exported JAR from project B actually contained an old version of `commons-io` which was prioritized over the one in project A since it was bundled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the project, go to Maven -> Reimport. This should show all the maven imports and update all the new jars.