# Maven version range does not get the latest version on IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

When I use **reimport** command on IntelliJ to get the latest version I keep having the following situtation:

```
<library.version>[0.2.2,)</library.version>
```

i.e. There's a `0.2.209` version but it keep giving me the `0.2.208`.

Comment: Have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16992262/1535071) answers?

Comment: What Maven version is used in IntelliJ IDEA for importing?

Comment: @CrazyCoder 3.3.9

Comment: @LorenaSalamanca I have, none of them solve my problem tho.

Comment: @FelipeBelluco ok, let's do some testing, can you update the question with the full dependency? Let's see if I get the same result :)