# Java: package org.bytedeco.javacv does not exist

Tags: java, javacv

I am trying to use [byteDeco JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) but even after adding the dependency I am getting the package `org.bytedeco.javacv` doesn't exist .

Tried both dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

BDW using IntelliJ as IDE. Am I missing something? I am unable to import any package with `org.bytedeco`

Comment: on the right side you have a "maven" small window with a refresh button in it. Try to click on it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven

Comment: Well ***winner winner, chicken dinner!*** thanks, @RC.

Comment: Let's mark this one as a duplicate then ;)

Comment: Sure, not an issue :)