# Can't build project through intellij-idea with maven, but through console command "mvn package" build successful

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I got a project written in java EE 5.
I use:

- Java 7
- Maven 3.5.4
- idea 2018.2.5x64

When you build a project through idea, the project is not built.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBG5p.png)

But when I run the `mvn package` through console, the process completes successfully

Help me please for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your maven dependencies in Intellij. Usually you should see a prompt asking you to do that.

Read this for more details on updating dependencies: [How can I make IntelliJ IDEA update my dependencies from Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven)

Comment: It doesn't help.