# lombok dependency import error in intelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

Recently, I am reading *Spring In Action*. When it came to using lombok dependency, I've got stuck. When I import lombok like it is described in the book:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

IntelliJ IDEA throws following error:

> fail to read artifact descriptor for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.8

When I use the latest maven code snippet from the lombok website (which references lombok version 1.18.10, see below) the error is gone.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I switch the lombok version back to 1.18.8 (see snippet below) the above-mentioned error also comes back. Why does this happen?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe try the answers provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor/13382634

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that your maven can't find the older lombok dependency locally. Try to update your maven project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven/16992262).

If you get further problems with the same error message (`fail to read artifact descriptor`) check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor/13382634).