# Intellij auto downloads when I do some pom changes at dependencies. Is this mvn install running at backgroud?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

When I do some changes at dependencies in pom.xml, *Intellij auto-downloads* them

Is this actually as `mvn install` running at background

If not whats the difference between these two situation(`mvn insatll` & `intellij auto-downlaod`)

As both are fetching dependencies for us !

Answer (score 0):

(By default?,) auto update is [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven).

**intellij auto-download** makes use of **mvn**:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206834305-Automatically-download-sources-documentation-from-maven-working-great