# How to add maven dependencies for "org.slf4j" in intellij idea?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have downloaded **slf4j-simple** from *[link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple)* and add it into pom.xml file. But I don't know how to add dependencies for that in IntelliJ IDEA. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you asking how to *refresh* IntelliJ to see changes to the pom.xml file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make IntelliJ IDEA update my dependencies from Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16992255/5221149)

Comment: yes that's my question.

Comment: but problem is that after refreshing maven. error still there it won't resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make IntelliJ IDEA update my dependencies from Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven)