# can not resolve symbol "javafx.scene.web"

Tags: javafx, webview

Using Intellij 2021.3.2, JavaFX version: 11.0.2+1.

I'm trying to add a JavaFX WebView to my application. My import statement does not compile:

```
import javafx.scene.web;
```

The compilation error:

> java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   class web
> location: package javafx.scene

As far as I can tell, JavaFX version 11 should contain the .web package. Maybe I have to install something specific to use it?

Comment: make sure the module javafx.web is added to build/runtime module path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application)

Comment: That sounds like good advice. How do I do that? Is that an intellij setting or a java setting, or what?

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to do it:

1. Create a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).
2. Edit `pom.xml`.
3. Add a dependency on `javafx-web`.

   - Use the same version as the rest of the JavaFX dependencies in that file.
   - Hit the refresh icon in the maven window to re-synchronize the Maven project with the IDE project.
4. Edit `module-info.java`.
5. Add the line `requires javafx.web;`.

Example POM excerpt:

```xml
…
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
…
```

Example `module-info.java`:

```java
module com.example.exfxwebview {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;


    opens com.example.exfxwebview to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.exfxwebview;
}
```

You will now be able to use [`WebView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) in your code.

---

Alternatively, take your existing project, follow the advice in the answer kleopatra linked:

- [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application)

and add in the `javafx.web` module where-ever that answer refers to adding modules.

The answer is similar to the following which discusses the `javafx.media` module:

- [Can not work with MediaPlayer class, javafx.media is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016623/can-not-work-with-mediaplayer-class-javafx-media-is-not-found)

I advise using the most recent stable version of Java and JavaFX for development, currently 20.0.2, not JavaFX 11, especially if you have a Mac with [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) ([M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#Apple_M1), [M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#Apple_M2)).  Only JavaFX 17.0.2+ works with those Macs.

Comment: That did it, thank you! I had to do a Maven Reload as well, but that pulled it in correctly.

Comment: @TroyCowan thanks for info, I updated the answer to add the refresh step.