# Keep getting a "java: module not found: javafx.web" on IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use WebView for one of my projects.

I imported it in pom.xml, added it on module-info.java, and was able to use it in my main class without IntelliJ throwing me any errors, but, whenever I run the program I get a "java: module not found: javafx.web" issue.

Does anyone know why its doing this?

The thing that's frustrating me the most is that IntelliJ does find the library. It queries the class and its methods.

**module-info.java**

```
module com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires org.fxmisc.richtext;

    opens com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt.core to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt.core;

    opens com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt.client to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt.client;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.gabrielgavrilov</groupId>
  <artifactId>cobolt</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Cobolt</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fxmisc.richtext/richtextfx -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
      <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
      <version>20</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt/com.gabrielgavrilov.cobolt.client.Cobolt</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using version `17.0.6` for `javafx-controls` and `javafx-fxml` but `20` for `javafx-web`?

Comment: Move your JavaFx dependency elements all together for easier reading.

Comment: Use a variable for the same version number of all the JavaFX-related elements.

Comment: Similar: [*can not resolve symbol "javafx.scene.web"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70942561/642706)