# How to play audio in Java using Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, audio

I need to play background music in a window using javafx. However, I am not able to find the correct imports in order to play it. Everything that I have seen other people do doesn't work, and I always get an error while importing something related to audio.

I tried importing javafx.media.Media, and javafx.media.MediaPlayer, but nothing worked. I also tried using the Jlayerlibrary from JavaZoom jlayer project, but that didn't work either, as I wasn't able to successfully import it.

Comment: Those aren't the correct imports. See the [`javafx.media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.media/module-summary.html) module documentation. Note that you will need to have that module as a dependency; [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) should be able to help with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Can't play wav or mp3 files with Javafx MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096610/cant-play-wav-or-mp3-files-with-javafx-mediaplayer-also-cant-play-wav-files-w/71099315#71099315), and [Can not work with MediaPlayer class, javafx.media is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016623/can-not-work-with-mediaplayer-class-javafx-media-is-not-found).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

The audio files must be in `.wav` format. The Format `.mp3` will not work.

**Code:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("backgroundMusic.wav");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);
Clip backgroundMusicClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
backgroundMusicClip.open(ais);
backgroundMusicClip.loop(0);

// ADDITIONAL
backgroundMusicClip.stop();
```

Comment: I tried this, but the imports still didn't work.

Comment: @YashKorgaonkar The `javax.sound` API is part of the standard library (unlike JavaFX). If these imports are not working, then there's something unusually wrong with your environment. You should edit your question to provide a [mre].