# java.lang.module.FindException: Module test not foundIntellidea

Tags: javafx

I am have this Exception please help me!
"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.Find Exception: Module test not found"

But i write VM option `"--module-path "D:\UT java\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"`

and i have module-info.java "

```
 requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires jdk.jfr;"
```

i add my sdk. And if i create javafx demo project and execute him it work. and if i start change fxml file and change controller i have this exception.
I have IntellIJIdea 2021, javafx-sdk-17.0.1, jdbc jr 8,11,16

Comment: That is a not a valid format for a `module-info.java` file.  See this [module tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) for examples of valid `module-info.java` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to fix:

1. Delete the JavaFX sdk (you don’t need it).
2. Delete old Java versions (they are obsolete).
3. Update your IntelliJ IDE and IDE plugins to the most recent release, 2021.3.2+.
4. [Create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) using JDK and JavaFX 17.0.2+.

   - Select Maven for the build system unless you know and prefer Gradle.
5. Do not set VM arguments, you don’t need them.

   - Adding modules via the `--add-modules` VM arguments is unnecessary when you have a valid `module-info.java` file.
   - The `--module-path` is still required so that the modules can be found, but Idea will provide the correct path for your modules automatically when it recognizes the modules through your Maven dependencies.
   - So you don't need to explicitly define the `--module-path` VM argument yourself for a Maven based build (that would be difficult to do anyway because the modules are all downloaded to different directories in your local maven repository).
6. Test it works following the Idea create new JavaFX project execution instructions.
7. Add additional modules one at a time by adding their maven dependency to `pom.xml` and the requires clause to `module-info.java`.

   - Ensure you [synchronize the Maven and Idea projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-update-my-dependencies-from-maven/16992262) between each
     addition.
   - See, for example, this question on correctly [adding the `javafx.media` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016623/can-not-work-with-mediaplayer-class-javafx-media-is-not-found).
   - Adding other modules such as `javafx.web`, `javafx.fxml` or `javafx.swing` follows a similar pattern.
8. Test between each addition by building and running the project, to ensure you haven’t broken anything.
9. Copy your original source code into the appropriate package directories under the new project source directory:

   ```
   src/main/java
   ```
10. Place resources in:

    ```
    src/main/resources
    ```

    following the [Eden resource location guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).
11. Fix any errors, ensure everything compiles and runs, then test it.

Comment: Thank you for your help my project is executed but now i have this problem can you help me? //PKIX path building failed

Comment: No. PKIX is a certificate error. Search for questions about that. If you can’t find an existing solution (unlikely), ask a new question with a [mcve] and the comets stack trace formatted as code.