# Problems building a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to upgrade a very old JavaFX application which uses in the [Main][1] view a set of controls from the packages **javafx.scene** such as **javafx.scene.SceneBuilder** or **javafx.scene.control.TextField**.
I have added the following dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>17.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to build the project, all Classes in the javafx.scene packages are not found.

Is there a separate dependency to add for this package ?
According to the product docs, only the above is mentioned.
Any help?
Thanks
[1]: https://github.com/fmarchioni/jboss-as-quickstart/blob/master/kitchensink-javafx/src/main/java/org/kitchensinkfx/view/Main.java

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909942/230513) illustrates removing builder dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll work on updates based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [getting started instructions at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

**Modularity**

When JavaFX was modularized and separated from the jdk in Java 11, previous code which relied on JavaFX being in the jdk stopped working. You need to provide the JavaFX modules and instructions on how to use them to the javac and java processes.

This class:

```
javafx.scene.control.TextField
```

Does exist in a modern JavaFX distribution.  But, to use it, you must either place

```
requires javafx.controls;
```

In a module-info.java file you add.

OR

Add the `javafx.controls` module via a command line switch.

Either way, the appropriate JavaFX modules (javafx.controls, javafx.graphics, etc.) need to also be on your module path.

The Java module system is complex and its use varies by environment.  To better understand, study a [tutorial on the module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) and the openjfx.io documentation.

**Builders**

The builder classes were deprecated and removed.

You need to change the code to use a constructor and relevant method calls on the constructed instance.

This class:

```
javafx.scene.SceneBuilder
```

No longer exists in a modern JavaFX distribution and its usage must be replaced as described above.

**Suggested approach**

If using Idea, I recommend following this:

- [process to import an existing project using the new JavaFX project wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498158/java-lang-module-findexception-module-test-not-foundintellidea/71500774#71500774).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Very useful indeed