# Where can I get javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils for Maven Java 18 in IntelliJ?

Tags: image, maven, javafx, swingutilities

I'm trying to add a feature to my JavaFX application to save a PNG image. The [solution](https://www.eehelp.com/question/save-the-image-painted-by-javafx-on-disk/) I've seen almost everywhere to convert a JavaFX *Image* to a writable buffer consists in using **SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(...)**.

After a few hours of research, the SwingFXUtils class definitely comes from the `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils` package, that should belong to the `javafx.swing` module.

However, the `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils` **package is not recognised** when I import it in a *.java* file in IntelliJ (unlike all my other JavaFX dependencies). I have tried adding `requires javafx.swing;` to my **module-info.java** though IntelliJ does not recognise either : **Module not found: javafx.swing | No documentation found**.

I thought the library may need to be added to the project manually, though I cannot find it on the internet. I wouldn't know how to add it to the project either, if I found it.

I also suspected the package was changed in Java 18, though it seems it's still here according to its documentation :
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html

**My module-info.java** :

```
module fr.gbernard.pixelartref {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.swing; // Module not found: javafx.swing

    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires java.desktop;

    opens fr.gbernard.pixelartref.view to javafx.fxml;
    exports fr.gbernard.pixelartref;
}
```

**All imports** in the file I want to use SwingFXUtils in :

```
package fr.gbernard.pixelartref.utils.netpng;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritablePixelFormat;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

**Libraries** :

```
Maven: org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.22
Maven: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.12
Maven: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.12
Maven: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.8.12
Maven: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.8.12
Maven: org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-core:12.2.02
Maven: org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.2.02
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:win:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:win:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:win:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:18-ea+62
Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:win:18-ea+62
Maven: org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.02
```

SDK : **openjdk-18**

IDE : **IntelliJ**

If you need any more information, please ask ^^

Comment: `org.openjfx:javafx-swing` is not in your pom.xml.

Comment: Follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016623/can-not-work-with-mediaplayer-class-javafx-media-is-not-found), except replace the word `media` with the word `swing`. Don't use the `ea` software versions, just use the release versions (currently `18.0.1`).