# import javafx in netbeans 13

Tags: java, javafx

I want to import javafx media player but it doesn't appear, I can just import java and javax tools.

Please how can I import javafx in a maven project??

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you're not using one of the java versions where javafx was part of the jdk. Did you add javafx as a dependency in your pom?

Comment: @jewelsea that's pretty much most of an actual answer right there

Comment: @clvrmnky I replaced the comment with an answer, as it is probably better that way as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to openjfx.io. Open the Getting Started section. Follow the net beans instructions in the sections titled "JavaFX and NetBeans", and "Modular with Maven":

- https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

If you need to use external 3rd party libraries which don't work well with JavaFX Modules, then follow the instructions "Non-modular with Maven" instead.

I advise you to use maven and follow the info on adding the media module here:

- [Can not work with MediaPlayer class, javafx.media is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016623/can-not-work-with-mediaplayer-class-javafx-media-is-not-found)

OR, use Bellsoft Liberica “Full JDK” or an equivalent that includes JavaFX modules.

- https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads

Make sure if you use Liberica that you choose "Full JDK", not "Standard JDK".